# Looping in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define loop
  (lambda (x proc)
    (when (not (= x 0))
      (eval proc)
      (loop (- x 1) proc))))
```

Is this the best way to create a loop function in Scheme?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number things a seasoned Schemer would do differently:

1. Use a more descriptive name for the procedure, such as `call-n-times`.
2. Use `times` or `count` (or `n`, if you call your procedure `call-n-times`) instead of `x`.
3. Use `zero?` instead of `(= ... 0)`.
4. Use `unless` instead of `(when (not ...) ...)`.
5. Not use `eval`, but instead pass in a lambda and invoke it directly.
6. Do the tail recursion using a named `let` so you don't have to re-pass the `proc` argument.

Putting all this together, we get:

```
(define (call-n-times n proc)
  (let loop ((n n))
    (unless (zero? n)
      (proc)
      (loop (- n 1)))))
```

Bonus points: allow the caller to pass additional arguments and pass them through to the given procedure:

```
(define (call-n-times n proc . args)
  (let loop ((n n))
    (unless (zero? n)
      (apply proc args)
      (loop (- n 1)))))
```